# What services or configuration can i use to encrypt data in use whithin Azure?

Tags: azure, encryption

I need to encrypt data in all of its stages (in transfer, at rest and in use). Preferrably in AES-CTR-256.
I found Always Encrypted, and that would be the perfect solution, but i dont have data in Azure SQL.
Are there more ways of implementing something similar to other services?

I dont know what to do, actually. I tried to find other possibilites, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Azure offers several mechanisms to encrypt data in transit and at rest. For data at rest, Azure Storage provides Storage Service Encryption (SSE) that automatically encrypts data before persisting it to Azure Storage and decrypts it before retrieval. Operating system and data disks used by VMs can also be encrypted.

Comment: Additionally, Azure SQL Database provides Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) at rest by default, allowing you to use Azure Key Vault and bring your own key (BYOK) functionality to control key management tasks including key permissions, rotation, deletion, and so on. For data in transit, you can use client-side encryption, HTTPS, or SMB 3.0. You can also enable encryption for traffic between your own virtual machines (VMs) and your users using Azure Virtual Networks and the industry-standard IPsec protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Azure service that provides encryption for data in use like Always Encrypted. However, you can use Azure Key Vault to store and manage cryptographic keys used for encryption and decryption in your application.

Comment: -   [Encryption in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/office-365-azure-encryption#encryption-in-azure)
-   [Azure security for cloud-native apps - Encryption in transit and at rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/azure-security#encryption-in-transit-and-at-rest)
-   [Azure security technical capabilities - Data security and encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/technical-capabilities#data-security-and-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers several mechanisms to encrypt data in transit and at rest.
For data at rest, Azure Storage provides [Storage Service Encryption (SSE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption) that automatically encrypts data before persisting it to Azure Storage and decrypts it before retrieval.

If you need to encrypt data in use, you can consider using [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16), which is a feature of Azure SQL Database that allows you to encrypt sensitive data within an application.

However, if you don't have data in Azure SQL, =you can use [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/key-vault/)  to store and manage cryptographic keys used for encryption and decryption in your application. Below is an example to use azure key vault to encrypt your data-

Here I am using `Azure Key Vault` to securely store the `Terraform` credentials it provides a centralized and secure way to manage sensitive information like `secrets` and `keys`.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
      alias           = "credentials"
      subscription_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.subscription_id.value
      tenant_id       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.tenant_id.value
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
    }
    data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      name                = "srikv05"
      resource_group_name = "Sri"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "subscription_id" {
      name         = "subscriptionid"
      key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }
    data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tenant_id" {
      name         = "tenantid"
      key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage_rg" {
      name     = "venkat-test-rg"
      location = "east us"
      provider = azurerm.credentials
    }
```

**Output:**
[image]

This approach enables you to store `Terraform` credentials securely using `Azure Key Vault's` advanced security features.

Reference:

- [Encryption in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/office-365-azure-encryption#encryption-in-azure)
- [Azure security for cloud-native apps - Encryption in transit and at rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/azure-security#encryption-in-transit-and-at-rest)
- [Azure security technical capabilities - Data security and encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/technical-capabilities#data-security-and-encryption)